# setting a different theme for specific category in wordpress

Tags: themes

I was wondering if and how is it possible in Wordpress to set a different theme for a specific category of contents (in my case the blog).

I'm on WP 3.3.1.

Thank you so much in advance.

Any help will be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: You can either get into http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates Category Templates or use a plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gys-themed-categories-2/

Comment: Just go to the Add New Plugins section of the WordPress and search for a plugin called [Multiple Themes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/).

Answer (score 1):

WordPress can only use **one Theme** at a time. You cannot (and, really, *should* not) change Themes on-the-fly. (There are edge cases; [search the Plugin repository for Theme Switcher Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=theme%20switch) for implementation examples.)

That said, that doesn't mean that *a **single Theme** can't output different styles based on the current context*; and, really, that's what you're after here.

The first step is understanding the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy); in your case, you're primarily interested in [Category templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display). The primary takeaway here is that you can use *specific template files* for specific category contexts; i.e. you can define a `category-foobar.php` template file to output the Foobar category archive index.

The second step is understanding the [`body_class()` template tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class), and the context-specific CSS classes that this tag adds to the HTML `<body>` tag. The primary takeaway here is that *WordPress will add category-specific CSS classes* to the HTML `<body>` tag for specific category contexts; i.e. WordPress will add `category` and `category-foobar` as classes on the Foobar category archive index, which you can target via CSS with e.g. `body.category-foobar`.

The rest becomes a matter of HTML and CSS, which is best left as an exercise for the reader.